How to retrieve the GeoDjango Point model lat and lon coordinates in Django values_list of objects
Would like to retrieve the GeoDjango Point model lat and lon coordinates from a values_list of objects. I'm only able to retrieve a full descriptive string such as "SRID=4326;POINT (1 1)". I need to just retrieve the lat and long numbers, ideally separately, but something such as "(1.000 1.000)" I can live with. Thank you.
Models.py
point = models.PointField(srid=4326,default='SRID=4326;POINT(0.0 0.0)',null=True,blank=True)
Views.py
Model.objects.all().values_list('point') returns for example "SRID=4326;POINT (1.000 1.000)" but...
Model.objects.all().values_list('point__x') or Model.objects.all().values_list('point__coords__x') do not work, and returns a "join on the field not permitted" error
